# Where is macOS Terminal.app's last window state stored on disk?

Tags: macos, terminal

In macOS, `Terminal.app`, like most native apps store their window state. So if you quit terminal and then relaunch, you get all your tabs back, and each tab is in the same working directory as before quitting. I want to restore this window session from another computer, but I cannot find where it is stored on disk. I have checked for `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal` and `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Terminal/Data/Library/Saved Application State`, neither is present on my system.

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` is present, but that appears to only store saved preferences, including optionally explicitly named and saved window-states, but not the implicit "last session" window state.

Can anyone help find where on disk the last session for Terminal is stored?

Comment: You are looking in the right folder (`~/Library/Saved Application State/`). Probably your Terminal "resume state" isn't on. You can turn it on for all applications by unchecking the option "Close windows when quitting an App" from the "General" panel in "System Preferences". Or you can turn it on specifically for Terminal entering the command: `defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true`

Comment: @Yoric could it be that `Saved Application State` is not retained in Time Machine backups? It just doesn't seem to be there

Comment: After reading the comment by kuzzuroo at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146301/what-would-the-downside-be-of-excluding-saved-application-state-from-time-mach, I checked `/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist` for `"Saved Application State" `. It was not there. I cannot account for why `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal` would be missing from `Backups.backupdb`

Comment: I'm not familiar with using TimeMachine, but it seems `Saved Application State` is automatically excluded. CarbonCopyCloner wrote a complete list of what's excluded based on Apple recommendation. I guess it should be similar with Time Machine: https://bombich.com/kb/ccc3/some-files-and-folders-are-automatically-excluded-backup-task

Comment: @Yoric This link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6983356 seems to confirm your suspicion; that Time Machine excludes `Saved Application State`. Well crap, I'm sad. At least we have an answer.

Comment: Apple must have changed this. I was able to restore these files using Time Machine today.
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/
1) Right click any file in the folder
2) Select "open with", choose other.
3) search for Time Machine
4) In the "Enable" drop down, select "all applications".
5) Double click "Time Machine.app" to open.
6) Browse, select all, and choose restore